# Insert a new row into a specific location in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of around 30 rows. I need to insert a new row specifically into the 3rd row. I tried manually giving it an 'id' value, hoping the auto-increment would take care of the rest but it's giving me a 'duplicate entry' error for the primary key.

Is there any way around this? It's a one-time fix so I dont need a 'flexible' solution or anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

execute this update before you insert the row with id=3:

```
update your_table set id=id+1 where id >= 3;
```

Comment: I would like to add a small specification: if the ID field is PRIMARY KEY, with your command you receive an error message (Duplicate Entry).
But if you change the order in which the records are processed (the one with ID value greater than the value with an ID less) your command does not fail.    UPDATE your_table SET id=id+1 WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY DESC   is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete all of the records and reinsert them in the order you want them, but that does not necessarily mean you will return them in the correct order.

If you need your results in a certain order, use the order by clause in your SQL.

Why would you need a record placed in the table in a certain order?

Comment: Efficiency.  Some rows belong together when being printed for instance.  Its rare, but there are cases where it makes sense for certain rows to be adjacent to each-other.